# Duplicando a ultima linha do arquivo .txt c++

Tags: c++, funções, arquivo, struct, while

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Produto
{
    string nomeProduto,quantidade,marca,preco;
};
void carregaProdutos(vector<Produto> &R)
{
    ifstream ler;
    Produto T;
    ler.open("Teste.txt",ios::in);
    while(ler.good())
    {
        ler>>T.nomeProduto>>T.quantidade>>T.marca>>T.preco;
        R.push_back(T);
    }
ler.close();
}
void salvaProdutos(vector<Produto> R){
    ofstream salva;
    salva.open("Teste.txt", ios::trunc);
    for(int i=0; i<R.size();i++)
    {
        salva<<R[i].nomeProduto<<" "<<R[i].quantidade<<" "<<R[i].marca<<" "<<R[i].preco<<endl;
    }
salva.close();
}
void inserirProduto()
{
    Produto P;
    ofstream inserir;
    inserir.open("Teste.txt",ios::app);
    cout<<"\tNome do produto:";
    cin>>P.nomeProduto;
    cout<<"\tQuantidade:";
    cin>>P.quantidade;
    cout<<"\tMarca:";
    cin>>P.marca;
    cout<<"\tPreco R$:";
    cin>>P.preco;
    inserir<<P.nomeProduto<<' '<<P.quantidade<<' '<<P.marca<<' '<<P.preco;

    inserir.close();
}
void apagarProduto()
{
    fstream abrir;
    fstream temp;
    abrir.open("Teste.txt",ios::in);
    temp.open("temp.txt",ios::out);
    string nomeApagar,n,q,m,p;
    cout<<"Informe o nome do produto para ser apagado:";
    cin>>nomeApagar;
    while(abrir.good())
    {
        abrir>>n>>q>>m>>p;
        if (nomeApagar!=n)
        {
            temp<<n<<' '<<q<<' '<<m<<' '<<p<<endl;
        }
    }
    abrir.close();
    temp.close();
    abrir.open("Teste.txt",ios::out);
    temp.open("temp.txt",ios::in);
    while(temp.good())
    {
        temp>>n>>q>>m>>p;
        abrir<<n<<' '<<q<<' '<<m<<' '<<p<<endl;
    }
    temp.close();
    abrir.close();
    remove("temp.txt");
}
int main() {
    vector<Produto> R;
    int rep;
    
    carregaProdutos(R);
    salvaProdutos(R);
    while(true){
    cout<<"\tO que deseja fazer\n";
    cout<<"\t1-Inserir produto\n\t2-Apagar produto\n\tOu aperte qualquer outro numero para sair:\n";
    cin>>rep;

    if(rep==1)
    {
        inserirProduto();
    }
    else if(rep==2)
    {
        apagarProduto();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    }
return 0; 
}
```

Fiz alguns testes no programa, e quando insiro alguns produtos e logo depois apago algum, o arquivo txt duplica a ultima linha.

Comment: Aqui: `while(temp.good())
    {
        temp>>n>>q>>m>>p;
        abrir<<n<<' '<<q<<' '<<m<<' '<<p<<endl;
    }` ele vai executar `abrir<<n<<' '<<q<<' '<<m<<' '<<p<<endl;` mesmo que tenha ocorrido EOF na linha anterior.

Comment: E como eu faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Logo após a leitura verifique se foi detectado o fim do arquivo e só faça a gravação caso não tenha sido detectado.